# Running shell commands within Python, can not debug other Python modules called

Tags: python, bash, shell, debugging, pycharm

I call shell commands from a Python script (init) to caffe functions, this specific example trains a model using solver prototxt. What it does is to use caffe framework's built in functions, such as "train" and pass arguments. The train code is mainly built in C++ but it calls a Python script for a custom data layer. When I run the script below, it works, however I can not debug the custom Python data layer that is called by the training process. I have placed breakpoints and I try to run debug inline but it just works completely disregarding those breakpoints in the custom Python data layer. It only debugs the breakpoints in the init. I am using PyCharm. What can I do to debug this custom layer?

```
# Make a copy of the current environment, then add a few additional variables
env = os.environ.copy()
env['HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK'] = '1'
env['PYTHONPATH'] = '.'
env['GLOG_logtostderr'] = '1'

subprocess.call([
"sampleexact/samplepath/build/tools/caffe", "train", "-solver",
"lstm_solver_flow.prototxt", "-weights",
"single_frame_all_layers_hyb_flow_iter_50000.caffemodel"], env=env)
```

Comment: If all else fails, you can do (on *nix) `sudo strace -p $PID` where `$PID` is the process ID of your misbehaving Python process.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will keep in mind. However, what I really need to do is to check the values. I could potentially print them out but there is too much to keep track of.

Comment: For anyone having similar issues, I was able to debug using pdb with the console. But not with pyCharm.